# Php rachet websocket experiencing one sided rate-limit

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, websocket, ratchet

## My setup

I have a (localhost) server, running php 8.0.1, that is hosting a [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) websocket, a very [basic setup](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) with a few call-handle functions added.

and I have 2 different clients:

- Web client
- Python client

The Web-client is just using basic [Javascript Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

And the Python-Client is using the [Python Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Module, specifically using the [asyncio websocket](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/asyncio/client.html).

---

## The issue

The python module seems to be getting rate-limited after roughly 1000 messages, halting the incomming data for about 2/3 seconds before allowing a small amount of data through again

However, the Javsascript client is not affected by this. Not getting rate-limited ever

---

## What I want

I want both the python client, as well as the javascript client to have no rate-limit what so ever.

---

## What I tried

I've looked through both the ratchet documentation as well as the python websockets documentation, but did not find much about the ratelimiting with these technologies.

I have also changed some of the asyncio connection arguments, (write_limit, max_queue, max_size) out of desperation to no avail.

---

## TLDR

Python websocket client is getting rate limited on my php ratchet websocket server, while my javascript websocket client is not getting rate-limited. And i want python to also be limitless